# How to find a bounded solution of a wave equation in one dimension by eigenvalue method.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

There is a problem to Find the bounded solution of the wave equation
$$ \dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}= 4\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \; \; \;\;  $$

Given boundary condition $$u(0,t) = \sin t,\;\; t>0;$$

And initial condition $$ u(x,0) = 0\;\; x>0\quad\text{and}\quad u_t(x,0) = e^{-x},$$

**My problem**
When I saw this problem I thought of using the solution $$u(x,t)= \sum \left( a_n \cos n \frac{\pi}{L} t + b_n\sin n \frac{\pi}{L}t \right)\sin(n \frac{\pi}{L} x) $$.

I have been put back by the boundary value condition.

May someone supply me the solution to this problem. I thank you in advance

**Follow up question**
I am very thankful to Martin and Jim. Their contribution has made me suggest that the solution to this is $$u(x,t)= \sin(x+2t)+\sin(x-2t)+\frac{1}{2} \sinh(x-2t)$$.

Is this answer correct?
If correct, Please help me know how I can move to this one using Martins method.

Comment: I was going to point out that the equation is the wave equation and the general solution is of the form $u(x,t) = f(x+2t) + g(x-2t)$, where $f, g$ are arbitrary functions and you have to use the boundary conditions to determine these functions. However, I'm having some problems satisfying the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Patrick Chidzalo : No, it's not correct : $u(x,t)=\sin(x+2t)+\sin(x-2t)+\frac{1}{2}\sinh(x-2t)$ is NOT solution of the PDE. Put it into the PDE and see that it doesn't agree. You have to realize that either the problem has no solution (as it is presently written), or there is a mistake in the writting ou your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you wrote works for the case where the domain is bounded, which is not the case here.

As stated, it seems as if the problem has no solution.

In general, as Jim mentioned, $u(x,t)=f(x+2t)+g(x-2t)$. 
From the initial conditions, 
$$
0=u(x,0)=f(x)+g(x),\ \ x>0. 
$$
This tells us that $g=-f$.
We have
$$
u_t(x,t)=2f'(x+2t)+2f'(x-2t)
$$From the second initial condition, 
$$
e^{-x}=4f'(x).
$$
So $f(x)=-\frac14\,e^{-x}+c$.

If we look at the boundary condition, 
$$
\sin t=f(2t)+g(-2t),\ \ t>0,
$$
so now we would need $$\sin t=f(2t)-f(-2t)=\frac14\,(e^{2t}-e^{-2t}),\ \ t>0.$$

The formula on the right is fairly close to $\sinh t$. Are you sure that was not the statement of the problem?

Comment: +1 to this answer. @Martin Argerami what could then one go from here?

Comment: @Patrick: unless I made a mistake, what I wrote shows that the problem as stated has no solution.